# Creating django pagination using generic view

Tags: django, html

I am facing a slight problem in django pagination using generic views, passing multiple models to a template with one of the models that has to paginated. The pager does not show next pages on my template,but produces just a single page.

Below is my code :

views.py:

```
class homeView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'success/home_page.html' 
    context_object_name="articles"  
    paginate_by = 3 

    def get_queryset(self):
        articles =Articles.objects.order_by('article_title')
        paginator = Paginator(articles,self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
           articles = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
           articles = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
           articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)    

        return articles

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(homeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['quote'] = Quotes.objects.order_by('quote')
        return context
```

Template:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {{ article.article_title}}
    {{ article.aticle_hit}}
{% endfor % %}
<div class="pagination">
   {% if articles.has_previous %}
       <a class="navlink" href="?page={{articles.previous_page_number}}">Prev</a>
   {% endif %}
   Page {{articles.number}} of {{articles.paginator.num_pages}}
   {% if articles.has_next %}
       <a class="navlink" href="?page={{articles.next_page_number}}">next</a>
   {% endif %}
</div>
```

Just page one of my paginated page shows. Next and previous do not work at all. Please help me with a better way to do pagination using generic view and passing multiple models in to a single template.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? You can delete the entire `get_queryset` method and just set `model = Articles` and keep paginate_by. It will work automatically.

Comment: get_queryset because  i am passing two models to one template .The problem i am facing my pagination does not show next and previous pages on html template

Comment: But you're not creating two models in get_queryset(). Trust  me, you don't need get_queryset. Delete it, add model, keep paginate_by. Then see if it still doesn't work, cause everything else looks normal.

Comment: Is showing an error .I am pretty new with django ,i will appreciate if you write down your code .In this way i will quickly understand your approach in solving the problem .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As said, trim down. If you get an error, post it, that will help.

```
class homeView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'success/home_page.html'
    context_object_name = "articles"
    paginate_by = 3
    model = Articles

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(homeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['quote'] = Quotes.objects.order_by('quote')
        return context
```

Comment: the code has been trim but i am still facing same problem .I have a total of 6 objects to display on my html template .But only  3  objects displayed without  showing  the  next button, to view the next  page that has the other 3 objects

Comment: It shows blank !!  Nothing shows at the pages section